# Laravel Eloquent Relationship returning empty result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing an issue with retrieving related data . I have defined the necessary relationships between my models, but when I try to access the related data, I'm getting an empty result. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have two models: `User` and `Post`. The `User` model has a one-to-many relationship with the Post model, where a user can have multiple posts.

User Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Post Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to retrieve a user's posts using the relationship, it returns an empty result:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$posts = $user->posts;
```

fetch All record from the database

Comment: Try getting the DB Query Log by wrapping code b/w `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `DB::getQueryLog();`

Comment: Can you share more about the Controller and migration files?

Comment: Have you checked whether you have any posts for the selected user `$user = User::find(1);`?

Comment: Please don’t forget to eager load post in your query. Else you will run into n+1 query problem. 

Secondly try it like User::with(‘posts’)->findOrFail(1);

Comment: eager loading doesn't really matter in this case ... is there a reason you are expecting this relationship to return a result? you have not provided any information about what data is actually in the database

Comment: Eager loading for a single record is not necessary; using either `with('posts')` (Eager Loading) or `->posts` (Lazy Loading) will execute a single extra query to load the `Post` records for this single `User` Model. Relationship looks ok, confirm that there are actually `posts` to load: `Post::where('user_id', 1)->count()`; if that is `0`, then you know why `$user->posts` is empty. If that is `1` (or more), then more digging is required.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `with`

```
$user = User::with('posts')->find(1);
```